# Node-JS link not opening in the mail

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I am trying to send a password resetting mail from node-js using node mailer and send-grid. I received the mail which is send by send-grid. Here's my code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVw7b.png)

And here's the issue i am facing
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94mwb.png)

when i tried to inspect it displays like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSUBZ.png)

Comment: Please use code blocks instead of images to share code. Using images makes code unreadable, especially from mobile clients. Wrap your multiline code in triple backticks (```) or use a single backtick (`) for simple inlined expressions. Read [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for help on text formatting.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question#:~:text=Images%20are%20harder%20to%20read,for%20us%20to%20do%20so.

Comment: Add header details of the received email

Answer (score 1):

Gmail is telling you that your email is not recognized as safe, probably because the sending server is not marked as allowed sender for your domain.
You're probably missing SPF, DKIM, DMARC or others anti-spam headers.

Check out sendgrid documentation on how to add SPF and DKIM records to your domain (you have to create/edit some TXT records in your DNS).

Answer (score 0):

This domain name is probably restricred as the spam in some email blacklist database.
Or probably your `<a>` is linking to localhost, try change or remove this link, or try adding only token code without `<a>`.

This change could fix the issue:
`tls: {rejectUnauthorized: false}`

```
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'host',
        port: 25,
        secure : false, // true for 465, false for other ports
        auth: {
            user: 'user',
            pass: 'password'
        },
        tls: {
            // do not fail on invalid certs
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        },
    });
```